# javascript alert TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, exception, typeerror

In the following javascript code,

```
        needSubIdCheck = $("#needSubIdCheck").text();
        liveSupplierCount = $("#liveSupplierCount").text();
        subIdCount = $("#subIdCount").text();

         if(needSubIdCheck == 'true')
         {
          if( liveSupplierCount > subIdCount  )
          {
              alert("subIDS Needs to be assigned");
            return false;
          }
        }
```

The above code gives, "Uncaught TypeError: alert is not a function" in the console. If I change the alert with window.confirm or console.log everything is fine. Can anyone help me to come out of this problem?

Comment: Somehow `alert` has been overridden. Add `console.log(typeof alert);` to see what it is. Perhaps you've got an element whose "id" is "alert". The code you posted by itself does not show what the problem is.

Comment: if I do console.log(typeof alert) it gives,Type Of Alert: string, how should I fix this problem

Comment: Find your variable named alert and change its name

Comment: nowhere i could find a variable named alert. and this problem happens only after i add the above code. previous alerts are also cribbing. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Chandramohan we cannot see the rest of your code, so it's impossible for anybody to help. The code you posted is part of a larger function (otherwise it's syntactically incorrect); why not start by posting that?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong in the given code. Can you check if you are using any pop-up-blockers, this could happen some times. Also check if you have override the alert (`var alert = ...`,`window.alert`) some were in the code. This could happen if you are using some external js files as well. For the time being comment out external js files and check if alert is working